# Trouble with using openmp with nested for loops and intrinsics

Tags: c, for-loop, openmp, nested-loops, intrinsics

So I'm having a little trouble figuring out the best way parallelizing these for loops using openmp. I'm guessing that biggest speed up would come from parallelizing the middle loop like I do here:

```
for(i = 0; i < m/16*16; i+=16){
    #pragma omp parallel for
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){

            C_column_start = C+i+j*m;

            c_1 = _mm_loadu_ps(C_column_start);
            c_2 = _mm_loadu_ps(C_column_start+4);
            c_3 = _mm_loadu_ps(C_column_start+8);
            c_4 = _mm_loadu_ps(C_column_start+12);

            for (k=0; k < n; k+=2){

                A_column_start = A+k*m;

                a_1 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i);
                a_2 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+4);
                a_3 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+8);
                a_4 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+12);

                b_1 = _mm_load1_ps(A_column_start+j);

                mul_1 = _mm_mul_ps(a_1, b_1);
                mul_2 = _mm_mul_ps(a_2, b_1);
                mul_3 = _mm_mul_ps(a_3, b_1);
                mul_4 = _mm_mul_ps(a_4, b_1);

                c_4 = _mm_add_ps(c_4, mul_4);
                c_3 = _mm_add_ps(c_3, mul_3);
                c_2 = _mm_add_ps(c_2, mul_2);
                c_1 = _mm_add_ps(c_1, mul_1);

                A_column_start+=m;

                a_1 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i);
                a_2 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+4);
                a_3 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+8);
                a_4 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+12);

                b_1 = _mm_load1_ps(A_column_start+j);

                mul_1 = _mm_mul_ps(a_1, b_1);
                mul_2 = _mm_mul_ps(a_2, b_1);
                mul_3 = _mm_mul_ps(a_3, b_1);
                mul_4 = _mm_mul_ps(a_4, b_1);

                c_4 = _mm_add_ps(c_4, mul_4);
                c_3 = _mm_add_ps(c_3, mul_3);
                c_2 = _mm_add_ps(c_2, mul_2);
                c_1 = _mm_add_ps(c_1, mul_1);

            }


            _mm_storeu_ps(C_column_start, c_1);
            _mm_storeu_ps(C_column_start+4, c_2);
            _mm_storeu_ps(C_column_start+8, c_3);
            _mm_storeu_ps(C_column_start+12, c_4);

        }

    }
```

However, this is currently giving me almost no speed up. Any tips would be awesome. I've been stuck for quite a while now.

Comment: Did you try to parallelize external loop?

Comment: I did. It also doesn't give me any speedup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, are you sure the loops are parallelizable? What is the range of the value `m`?

When all three nested loops are parallelizable and `m` is sufficiently large (say at least 16 or so), then parallelizing the *outer most loop* will be most beneficial. Parallelizaing inner loops may have severe forking-joining overhead from `omp parallel for`.

For the low speedup, here is some checklist:

1. Are you sure all cores are utilized? Check a sort of task manager. Since no synchronization except for the implicit barrier of `omp parallel for`, all cores are should be utilized.
2. Is `m` a huge number? And, what is the computation length? If `m` is huge while the computation is small, the parallel overhead due to `omp parallel for` may offset the benefit of the parallelization. When you parallelize an inner loop, the trip count (e.g., `m`) should not be huge.
3. [False sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) could be a reason. If your code modifies a lot of memory, it may cause false sharing, and the speedup could be hurt.